# How to crop objects from Hololens spatial mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens

trying to save the 3D mesh of an object (a cup) from the spatial mesh that Hololens generates. I find the coordinates of the cup using image processing (from Hololens video camera), and put a virtual box around it that serves as bounding box of the cup. So Whenever I send a raycast from the user's position to the box position, it hits the boundary I need to cut out.

My next step is to crop this part of spatial mesh and save it. And I don't know how. The main problem is that if I save the mesh from device portal and try to process it, the coordinates I have saved for my ROI will not be valid anymore. So I need to read the spatial mapping data of that region right away from the environment.

I appreciate your help in advance.